# Transactional Email Service with a lot of complex personalization

Tags: email

We are a dating application that wants to engage our users and thereby we want the ones in a week to send to our users report email about their activity, And of course the activity of every use should be unique.

Here is the example of the report, we want to deliver:

```
Hi, `User`,
You are receiving this notice because you have unread messages!
Do not miss your chance, maybe one of these messages were sent by your significant other!
Unread messages  from these users:
    Maria, 39, Rostov, link to profile of Maria, link to image of Maria
    MIA, 33, Minsk, link to profile of MIA, link to image of MIA
    Elena, 33, Kiev,link to profile of Elena, link to image of Elena
Click here to see all messages
```

I would like to use the one of leading Transactional or Marketing Email Services, but I don't know which one of them could give us solution to this need.

Comment: Mailchimp is Best. If you want to try Bronto then it is also good. This question may help you -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437808/email-marketing-newsletters-in-magento/30439043#30439043

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bulk or Marketing Email service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30509629/bulk-or-marketing-email-service)

Comment: Mailchimp is really does very serious job, but as far as I investigated they doesn't support that kind of flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used MailJet email transactional service for this matter. They support possibility to add unlimited number of custom properties.

So far I advanced very well with the task doing the following:

1. Added custom properties for all needed properties
2. I've uploaded  contact list details with all data via a CSV file
3. I've written a raw html template and bounded the template's placeholders to the custom properties of list details

For example:

```
<div class="new__faces__img"><img src='[[data:visitor1.photo]]'></div>
<div class="new__faces__name">
  <span>[[data:visitor1.name]]</span>, [[data:visitor1.age]]
</div>

> other visitors ...

<div class="new__faces__img"><img src='[[data:visitor12.photo]]'></div>
<div class="new__faces__name">
  <span>[[data:visitor12.name]]</span>, [[data:visitor12.age]]
</div>
```